# Fireplace floor doors

Tags: vent, fireplace

There are two rectangles on the bottom of the fireplace. One more in the middle and another to the back right. What is the purpose of either?

Comment: Picture will help, but probably vents to either let air into the fire box or to circuit air around the box to heat up and come out of the top.

Comment: or to sweep ashes into a basement-level bin/clean-out, but again, pictures would help.